# Can I run the same Minecraft Account on Multiple Computers at the same time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am going to purchase an account for Minecraft Java Edition, however, I wanted to know if I could use the same account on multiple computers at the same time, so I could be playing Minecraft on my laptop and my little brother could be playing Minecraft on another laptop at the same time as me on the same account (this is for singleplayer not multiplayer).